# When to panic and flee?

Tags: adom

Is it possible to see some stats of an entity on screen. Or perhaps some indication of how hard it is compared to the player?

I just played this game 2 times both of the times i was hacking through everything i was encountering very easily until i encountered a single entity which killed me in 2 or 3 blows. I would like to identify these types of enemies before engaging them in melee combat so i could flee if my odds of winning would be grim.

Comment: Apparently Ctrl+1 is "look". Does that allow you to examine enemies?

Comment: CTRL+1 is not "looK" for me. I can press L but that just tells me what it is and if it is injured.

Comment: Alright. I was going by a manual I found. It may be out of date. I haven't played adom, but I play a few other roguelikes which have 'examine' functions, so I tried to find something similar.

Comment: If adom is like many other roguelikes, it requires meta-experience to judge the difficulty of monsters based on what they are... and even then there are exceptions. Ware the Gnome with a Wand of Death.

Comment: Most monsters tend to allow you to gather a lot more information on them if you Look at them.  I think there's a key you have to press after you've targetted them to get the expanded info.

Comment: Still don't have it, there seems to be just that look around button that gives little info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ADoM version 1.1.1, creatures can be examined by hitting <kbd>l</kbd> (for look), selecting the creature you want to know more about, then hitting <kbd>m</kbd>. This will give you a description of it, as well as properties your current character has observed - initially you will probably know its speed (if you've seen it move). This will fill up as you observe the creature type do more stuff and fight it - expect to know its average HP, DV/PV values and so on. Keep in mind that there is a degree of randomness to creatures' attributes, and that creatures can level up. If the short description (before you hit <kbd>m</kbd>) says something like "it looks experienced", it's not just fluff.

There are also items and abilities that allow you to learn more of your opponents, but explaining those would be a spoiler.

Like most roguelikes, ADoM requires a lot of player skill and memorisation (or record-keeping): once you've encountered a creature, remember what went wrong, so next time you're prepared or at least know to use your contingency items. Losing is a (major) part of the game. ADoM is one of the harder and more unforgiving roguelikes. Expect to lose a lot, and enjoy your time in the Drakalor Chain!